# What's the best way in terminal to move a file from deep in one directory to deep into another?

Tags: macos, terminal

E.g. `/desktop/a/b/c/file.txt` and I want to move the text file to `/desktop/x/y/z/`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at the `mv` command?

`mv /desktop/a/b/c/file.txt /desktop/x/y/z/`

will do what you want.

Read about `mv` by typing `man mv` from the command prompt in Terminal.app.

Comment: Thanks!  I was also curious though if there was perhaps a more efficient way of doing so (say I need to go deep into both directories - is that still my only option?)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but the `mv` command can go as deep into a directory as your system will allow.

Comment: To avoid having to type out all the directory names you can use tab completion by typing the first few letters of a name and then pressing Tab.

Comment: drag the file or folder into terminal and it will complete the path.  so "mv <drag orig file> <drag dest folder>" if that makes sense

Comment: if it's a common thing you can symlink both deep directories and then mv ~/locA/foo.txt ~/locB

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `bash` (or similar) shell and you've visited both directories in succession, you could use the `$OLDPWD` environment variable:

```
cd /desktop/a/b/c
cd /desktop/x/y/z
mv $OLDPWD/file.txt .
```

or

```
cd /desktop/x/y/z
cd /desktop/a/b/c
mv file.txt $OLDPWD/.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are repeating the same move every time (i.e. from the same directory to the same directory), then you could create a bash shell function to greatly simplify the task.  You could edit your ~/.bash_profile file to contain the following shell function:

```
mvdeep(){
  mv "~/Desktop/a/b/c/$1" "~/Desktop/x/y/z/"
}
```

Then, save your changes to .bash_profile, open Terminal, and run the following to load the changes:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

From thereafter, if you had a file called "test.txt" in the "~/Desktop/a/b/c/" directory, you could move it to the "~/Desktop/x/y/z/" directory simply by using this command in terminal:

```
mvdeep test.txt
```

Search the web for "bash shell function examples" for more information about creating these for your needs.